# Font-Awesome loading the icons as squares

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I had installed the font-awesome free version in my pc and tried to run, using a icon in my page,but this doenst work. I'm using a local link to load the font-awesome css,not taking directly from the web. My font-awesome is free version 5.15.2

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.min.css">
```

Here is the icon I'm trying to use

```
<i class="fas fa-paw"></i>
```

Comment: You don't need to use both the .css and minified .min.css version, just one of them.  And, what do you see in your devtools console, and when you use inspect on the incorrectly rendered icon? Please [edit] your question to explain.

Comment: I'm not sure about that path syntax, try the `cdn` version see if that works

Answer (score -1):

Have you inserted the webfonts folder in your website?

You will have something like that:

- CSS

  - bootstrap.css
- JS

  - bootstrap.js
- webfonts

  - all the font awesome web fonts are here.